# Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts in C# using SSH.Net Tunnel

Tags: mysql, ssh, portforwarding

I'm trying to connect to a remote mysql server using a SSH tunnel set up using OpenSSH key file and SSH.Net library as shown in the code section below...

```
try
{
    PrivateKeyFile pkfile = new PrivateKeyFile("C:\\Users\\OpenSSHKey", "mypassword");
    var client = new SshClient("servername.com", 22, "myusername", pkfile);
    client.Connect();
    if (client.IsConnected)
    {
        var local = new ForwardedPortLocal(22, "localhost", 3306);
        client.AddForwardedPort(local);
        try
        {
            local.Start();
        }
        catch (SocketException se)
        {

        }
        string connStr = "server=localhost;user=mysql_username;database=database_name;port=3306;password=MyDBPassword;";
        MySqlConnection sql = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
        sql.Ping();
        try
        {
            sql.Open();
        }
        catch (MySqlException se)
        {
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
}
```

the tunnel is definitely set up because it throws the following error "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts" on the sql.Open() call...

Im sure the database is on the server named mysername because I can connect to it using putty or workbench with the credentials used in the MYSQL connection string... I hope someone can help

Comment: the line `var e = se.Data` is useless at the moment.

Comment: yes... I was trying to bubble up the validation errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just solved exactly this problem myself. Simply change your ForwardedPortLocal to:

```
    var local = new ForwardedPortLocal("127.0.0.1", 3306, "127.0.0.1", 3306);
```

In your original, you were giving the source port as `22`. However, your MySql connection would have been connecting to port `3306` on your local machine (which you would then tunnel across to port 3306 on the destination), so you need to ensure that the forwarded port is listening locally on 3306 to start with.

In addition, I've changed `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`. A secondary issue I tripped over was that `localhost` on my machine was actually resolving to `::1`, an IPv6 address, and the destination server didn't 'speak' IPv6. By switching this to the `127.0.0.1` (IPv4's version of localhost), it ensures that IPv4 is used by default.

Comment: Hi Adrian Wragg thanks for your answer... I abandoned that part of the project for some time now cos its was taking a long time to solve... I'm going back to it sometimes this week.. So much appreciate your input. Thanks

Comment: No problem - I'd actually had a related problem, asked it as a question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18507945/creating-a-forwarded-port-within-an-ssh-tunnel), solved it myself then noticed your question was hitting an overlapping issue.