# Creating a forwarded port within an SSH tunnel

Tags: c#, ssh, portforwarding, ssh.net

I'm attempting to use [SSH.NET](http://sshnet.codeplex.com/) to create a tunnel from `localhost:3306` to port 3306 on a remote machine:

```
  PrivateKeyFile file = new PrivateKeyFile(@" .. path to private key .. ");
  using (var client = new SshClient(" .. remote server .. ", "ubuntu", file))
  {

      client.Connect();
      var port = new ForwardedPortLocal(3306, "localhost", 3306);
      client.AddForwardedPort(port);
      port.Start();

            // breakpoint set within the code here

      client.Disconnect();
  }
```

When the breakpoint is hit, `client.IsConnected` is returning `true`, but `telnet localhost 3306` is not connecting. If I create the connection using Putty instead, and set up the same tunnel there, it succeeds. What have I missed?

Comment: Do you get a specific warning for the telnet application? Does it close? Binary connection data may not be displayed...

Comment: It hangs, failing to connect. When using Putty I get a string of data.

Comment: Try [this link](http://sshnet.codeplex.com/discussions/348423): I think disconnecting the client is the issue. And if you break between `Start` and `Disconnect` you may also halt the forwarding.

Comment: There seem to be a number of bugs in older versions of the library as well, make sure you are using the latest version.

Comment: @owlstead Thanks - I've checked, and I'm using 2013.4.7.0, the latest version.

Comment: @owlstead The client isn't disconnecting, and I'm not 'breaking' as such - I just have a breakpoint that the code hits, at which point I go to my telnet client. Note that the code I've commented out is designed to use a tunnel, and if I run that independently (with the tunnel created using Putty instead) it succeeds.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

By changing the parameters of ForwardedPortLocal to:

```
    var port = new ForwardedPortLocal("localhost", 3306, "localhost", 3306);
```

(to make it explicit which interface I was binding to), and adding the following code in just before `port.Start();`:

```
    port.RequestReceived += delegate(object sender, PortForwardEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.OriginatorHost + ":" + e.OriginatorPort);
    };
```

I noticed the following being output:

```
    ::1:60309
```

The `e.OriginatorHost` part of this was `::1`, which is the IPv6 equivalent of `localhost`; however, the destination server was using IPv4. Changing the parameters to:

```
    var port = new ForwardedPortLocal("127.0.0.1", 3306, "localhost", 3306);
```

forced the tunnel to run over IPv4 instead, and my code then worked exactly as I'd expected it to.

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution. I tried to work on this since hours >.<

Comment: See my question if your struggling like I was with a local MySQL instance on your dev machine :-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40592492/ssh-access-using-renci-ssh-to-mysql-server/40606542#40606542

Answer (score 0):

After hitting the same problem and analyzing it, and considering I came to the conclusion that it is a bug (though it might be considered arguable, clearly the behavior surprises users of SSH.NET API).

So I reported it on [Unexpected behavior (a.k.a. bug) on local tunnel · Issue #117 · sshnet/SSH.NET · GitHub](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET/issues/117).

Until it is fixed, the workaround in [c# - Creating a forwarded port within an SSH tunnel - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18507945/creating-a-forwarded-port-within-an-ssh-tunnel/18508735#18508735) works.