# C# SSH tunnel to MySQL server

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, ssh

I am trying to write a simple program to connect to a MySQL remote server that can only be connected to via SSH.

It reports the SSH connects and that the port forwards but then states that it cannot connect to any of the specified hosts?

Have I configured this wrong?

Below is the console output and the code:

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System.Web;
using System.Windows.Forms;
//Add MySql Library
using MySql.Data.Entity;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using MySql.Data.Types;

// SSH
using Renci.SshNet;
using Renci.SshNet.Common;

namespace MySQL_Console
{
    class MainClass
    {

        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            PasswordConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new PasswordConnectionInfo ("mytestdb.co.uk", "root", "password123");
            connectionInfo.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds (30);

            using (var client = new SshClient(connectionInfo)) {
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine ("Trying SSH connection...");
                    client.Connect();
                    if (client.IsConnected) 
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine ("SSH connection is active: {0}", client.ConnectionInfo.ToString());
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine ("SSH connection has failed: {0}", client.ConnectionInfo.ToString());
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine ("\r\nTrying port forwarding...");
                    var portFwld = new ForwardedPortLocal(Convert.ToUInt32(4479), "localhost", Convert.ToUInt32(3306)); 
                    client.AddForwardedPort(portFwld);
                    portFwld.Start();
                    if (portFwld.IsStarted) 
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine ("Port forwarded: {0}", portFwld.ToString());
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine ("Port forwarding has failed.");
                    }

                } 
                catch (SshException e) 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine ("SSH client connection error: {0}", e.Message);
                }
                catch (System.Net.Sockets.SocketException e) 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine ("Socket connection error: {0}", e.Message);
                }

            }

            Console.WriteLine ("\r\nTrying database connection...");
            DBConnect dbConnect = new DBConnect ("localhost", "test_database", "root", "passwrod123", "4479");

            var ct = dbConnect.Count ("packages");
            Console.WriteLine (ct.ToString());
        }
    }

    // MySQL DB class
    class DBConnect
    {
        private MySqlConnection connection;

        private string server;
        public string Server
        {
            get
            {
                return this.server;
            }
            set
            {
                this.server = value;
            }
        }

        private string database;
        public string Database
        {
            get
            {
                return this.database;
            }
            set
            {
                this.database = value;
            }
        }

        private string uid;
        public string Uid
        {
            get
            {
                return this.server;
            }
            set
            {
                this.server = value;
            }
        }

        private string password;
        public string Password
        {
            get
            {
                return this.password;
            }
            set
            {
                this.password = value;
            }
        }

        private string port;
        public string Port
        {
            get
            {
                return this.port;
            }
            set
            {
                this.port = value;
            }
        }

        //Constructor
        public DBConnect(string server, string database, string uid, string password, string port = "3306")
        {
            this.server = server;

            this.database = database;
            this.uid = uid;
            this.password = password;
            this.port = port;

            Initialize();
        }

        //Initialize values
        private void Initialize()
        {
            string connectionString;
            connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";
            connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        }


        //open connection to database
        private bool OpenConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("MySQL connected.");
                return true;
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                //When handling errors, you can your application's response based on the error number.
                //The two most common error numbers when connecting are as follows:
                //0: Cannot connect to server.
                //1045: Invalid user name and/or password.
                switch (ex.Number)
                {
                    case 0:
                    Console.WriteLine("Cannot connect to server.  Contact administrator");
                    break;

                    case 1045:
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid username/password, please try again");
                    break;

                    default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Unhandled exception: {0}.", ex.Message);
                    break;

                }
                return false;
            }
        }

        //Close connection
        private bool CloseConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Close();
                return true;
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return false;
            }
        }

        //Insert statement
        public void Insert()
        {
            string query = "INSERT INTO tableinfo (name, age) VALUES('John Smith', '33')";

            //open connection
            if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
            {
                //create command and assign the query and connection from the constructor
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);

                //Execute command
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                //close connection
                this.CloseConnection();
            }
        }

        //Update statement
        public void Update(string tableName, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> setArgs, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> whereArgs)
        {
            string query = "UPDATE tableinfo SET name='Joe', age='22' WHERE name='John Smith'";

            //Open connection
            if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
            {
                //create mysql command
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
                //Assign the query using CommandText
                cmd.CommandText = query;
                //Assign the connection using Connection
                cmd.Connection = connection;

                //Execute query
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                //close connection
                this.CloseConnection();
            }
        }

        //Delete statement
        public void Delete(string tableName, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> whereArgs)
        {
            string query = "DELETE FROM tableinfo WHERE name='John Smith'";

            if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
            {
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                this.CloseConnection();
            }
        }

        //Select statement
        public List<string> Select(string queryString)
        {
            string query = queryString;

            //Create a list to store the result
            List<string> list = new List<string>();

            //Open connection
            if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
            {
                //Create Command
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
                //Create a data reader and Execute the command
                MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                //Read the data and store them in the list
                int fieldCOunt = dataReader.FieldCount;
                while (dataReader.Read())
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < fieldCOunt; i++) {
                        list.Add(dataReader.GetValue(i).ToString());
                    }
                }

                //close Data Reader
                dataReader.Close();

                //close Connection
                this.CloseConnection();

                //return list to be displayed
                return list;
            }

            return list;

        }

        //Count statement
        public int Count(string tableName)
        {
            string query = "SELECT Count(*) FROM " + tableName;
            int Count = -1;

            //Open Connection
            if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
            {
                //Create Mysql Command
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);

                //ExecuteScalar will return one value
                Count = int.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar()+"");

                //close Connection
                this.CloseConnection();

                return Count;
            }

            return Count;

        }

        //Backup
        public void Backup()
        {
            try
            {
                DateTime Time = DateTime.Now;
                int year = Time.Year;
                int month = Time.Month;
                int day = Time.Day;
                int hour = Time.Hour;
                int minute = Time.Minute;
                int second = Time.Second;
                int millisecond = Time.Millisecond;

                //Save file to C:\ with the current date as a filename
                string path;
                path = "C:\\" + year + "-" + month + "-" + day + "-" + hour + "-" + minute + "-" + second + "-" + millisecond + ".sql";
                StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(path);


                ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
                psi.FileName = "mysqldump";
                psi.RedirectStandardInput = false;
                psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                psi.Arguments = string.Format(@"-u{0} -p{1} -h{2} {3}", uid, password, server, database);
                psi.UseShellExecute = false;

                Process process = Process.Start(psi);

                string output;
                output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                file.WriteLine(output);
                process.WaitForExit();
                file.Close();
                process.Close();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error {0}, unable to backup!", e.Message);
            }
        }

        //Restore
        public void Restore()
        {
            try
            {
                //Read file from C:\
                string path;
                path = "C:\\MySqlBackup.sql";
                StreamReader file = new StreamReader(path);
                string input = file.ReadToEnd();
                file.Close();


                ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
                psi.FileName = "mysql";
                psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                psi.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
                psi.Arguments = string.Format(@"-u{0} -p{1} -h{2} {3}", uid, password, server, database);
                psi.UseShellExecute = false;


                Process process = Process.Start(psi);
                process.StandardInput.WriteLine(input);
                process.StandardInput.Close();
                process.WaitForExit();
                process.Close();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error {0}, unable to Restore!", e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `DBConnect` code is outside of your `using SshClient`statement, meaning that the SSH connection created by the `client` object is not accessible after the using clause. Is this intended?

Comment: Thanks, moved it into the using statement as that was not intended :)

Comment: Hi Nathan, I'm using your code, but I get the exact error and when I change the port to the new port I have specified I get an error contact system administrator!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a forwarded port within an SSH tunnel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18507945/creating-a-forwarded-port-within-an-ssh-tunnel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost, or more generally IPAddress.Loopback.ToString(). Also, you don't need to explicitly cast to uint32. So you should try something like:

```
var portFwld = new ForwardedPortLocal(4479, IPAddress.Loopback.ToString(), 3306);
```

If that doesn't work, try also specifying the server name, something like:

```
var portFwld = new ForwardedPortLocal(IPAddress.Loopback.ToString(), 4479, "servername_goes_here", 3306);
```

Comment: What namespace does IPAddress fall under? :)

Comment: System.Net.IPAddress :)

Comment: ForwardedPortLocal take string, uint, string, uint. How can I convert ipaddress to uint?

Comment: ForwardedPortLocal take string, uint, string, uint so I had to convert IPAddress.Loopback.ToString() to a uint but now my outBound port is out of range. How do I choose the best port?

Comment: `var portFwld = new ForwardedPortLocal(IPAddress.Loopback.ToString(), "hsdev.co.uk", 3306);` This gives me: Port forwarded: Renci.SshNet.ForwardedPortLocal but the DB still complains it can't connect to host is my connection string OK?

Comment: `mysql error 1042 can't get hostname for your address`

Comment: Edited the second part of my answer (the part which also specified the server name) so that the parameters are in the correct order. My mistake, you do of course not need to convert the IP address to uint...