# Connection to MySQL from .NET code over an SSH.NET ForwardedPortLocal does not work

Tags: c#, mysql, ssh, tunnel, ssh.net

I have to access the database in MySQL that is on the computer with IP (1.1.1.1) with an external network.

I created a tunnel with SSH.NET, but I can't access the IP (1.1.1.1) of the computer where the database is located in MySQL.

Up to the Public IP the tunnel seems to work, but I can't access the Computer IP (1.1.1.1), since I didn't understand how SSH.NET works.
Using PuTTY I enter the public IP of the port and in the SSH tunnel section I insert the IP computer (1.1.1.1) with port 3306 and it works very well.
The code is this

```
using (var client = new SshClient("ip public", port, "user", "password")) 
{
    client.Connect();
    if (client.IsConnected)
    {
        var portForwarded = new ForwardedPortLocal("127.0.0.1",22, "1.1.1.1",3306);
        client.AddForwardedPort(portForwarded);
        portForwarded.Start();

        string db = @"Server=127.0.0.1;Port=3306;Database=xxx;Uid=root;Pwd=xxx;";
        {
            var mySQLCon = new MySqlConnection(db);

            mySQLCon.Open();

            if (mySQLCon.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                MainWindow stx = new MainWindow(db);
                stx.ShowDialog();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Am I wrong to put the parameters in `ForwardedPortLocal`?

```
ForwardedPortLocal("127.0.0.1",22, "1.1.1.1",3306);
```

I wanted to know if I entered the parameters in `ForwardedPortLocal` correctly, or where I am wrong in making tunnels with SSH.NET ...

Comment: See connectionstrings : https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/

Comment: If the mysql is running on server 1.1.1.1 then you should have `Server=1.1.1.1` in connection string

Comment: This tutorial walks you through all the steps: https://mysqlconnector.net/tutorials/connect-ssh/

Comment: BTW I hope you're not actually using `1.1.1.1`, since that's Cloudflare's public DNS resolver: https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/dns/what-is-1.1.1.1/

Answer (score 1):

The `boundPort` argument of `ForwardedPortLocal` is the local port which will be forwarded.  That's the port that you connect to with MySQL client. So not `22`.

While you can hard-code a port like `3306`, you better let SSH.NET auto-assign a free local port by omitting that parameter:

```
var portForwarded = new ForwardedPortLocal("127.0.0.1", "1.1.1.1", 3306);
```

And then use `ForwardedPortLocal.BoundPort` in your connection string, instead of hard-coding `3306`.

---

See also:

- [Connection to MySQL from .NET using SSH.NET Library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32603982/850848#32605335)
- [SSH tunneling a MySQL connection using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32752478/850848)