# How to connect to msSql over SSH connection

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssh

I have studied several SO questions but can't get this to connect - very confused about what IP and ports go where in the SO questions' descriptions aka the connection setup. SO questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32752478/ssh-tunneling-a-mysql-connection-using-c-sharp), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57982706/connection-to-mysql-from-net-code-over-an-ssh-net-forwardedportlocal-does-not-w), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32752478/ssh-tunneling-a-mysql-connection-using-c-sharp), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26426152/c-sharp-ssh-tunnel-to-mysql-server) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32603982/connection-to-mysql-from-net-using-ssh-net-library#32605335)

I have port forwarding on the remote router that forwards  to the remote PC. The SSH server also listens on the `<remoteIP>` that is forwarded. I can manually ssh to the remotePC with `ssh userName@<remoteRouterIP> -p <remotePort>`

And once connected, I can connnect to the mssql with `sqlcmd -C -S localhost -U SA`

FYI - I am connecting from a Windows PC to the server that is on a headless Debian server. Where am I getting it wrong? Should I change the remote PC mssql listening port(1433) to `<remotePort>`? The `client.Connect();` seems successfull, I get error `The remote computer refused the network connection`

UPDATE:
I changed the connectionstring as according to `AlwaysLearning`'s comment below, and change the port in that string to the allowed port in router settings that are forwarded to the PC.  I now get this error:

`System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake.`

```
var privateKey = new PrivateKeyFile(@"C:\Users\...\.ssh\id_ed25519", "<passPhrase>");
var keyFiles = new[] { privateKey };
var methods = new List<AuthenticationMethod>();
methods.Add(new PrivateKeyAuthenticationMethod("<remotePCUserName>",keyFiles));

Debug.WriteLine("SSHTest begins:");
var connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo("<remoteRouterIP>",<port>, "userName", methods.ToArray());
string sqlConnectionString = @"server=tcp:127.0.0.1, <remotePC_ForwardingPort>; Initial Catalog=<dbName>;Integrated Security=False;User ID=SA;Password=<password>; TrustServerCertificate=True";            
using (var client = new SshClient(connectionInfo))
{
    try
    {
        client.Connect();
        if(client.IsConnected) 
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("SSH connection success: {0}", client.ConnectionInfo.ToString());
            var portFWD = new ForwardedPortLocal("127.0.0.1",<remoteRouterPort>, "127.0.0.1", <remoteRouterPort>);
            client.AddForwardedPort(portFWD);
            portFWD.Start();
            if(portFWD.IsStarted) 
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Port forwarded: {0}", portFWD.ToString());
                DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
                try
                {
                   using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString))
                   {
                        using (SqlDataAdapter adaptor = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Table", sqlConnectionString))
                        {
                            adaptor.Fill(dataTable);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Port forward FAIL: {0}", portFWD.ToString());
                    Debug.WriteLine(ex);
                }
            }
        }
        else { Debug.WriteLine("SSH connection failed: {0}", client.ConnectionInfo.ToString()); }
    }
    catch(Exception ex) { }
}
```

Is there a setting at the remote PC to be set where SSH forwards on specific port to mssql's listenening port?  As I understand, that forwarding is done in the code above?

Comment: What's the exact error you're getting

Comment: `Port` is not an SqlConnectionString property. Have you considered `Server=tcp:localSshTunnelNameOrIpAddress,portNumber;` where `tcp:` will force use of the the TCP/IP client protocol, `,` separates the tunnel address from its port number and `portNumber` comes from `portFWD.BoundPort`?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning , other So questions and answers use `Port` in the connection string... ?     I have tried your setup as well however and no luck. I have "hard coded" the portnumber in `new ForwardedPortLocal`. So no need to use the .BountPort then

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, fyi - I updated the question

Comment: @AlwaysLearning what do you mean by `localSshTunnelNameOrIpAddress` ?

Comment: An SSH tunnel has two ends: the local end (e.g.: `127.0.0.1:2345`) that is managed by the SSH client, and the remote end (e.g.: `a.b.c.d:1433`) that is managed by the SSH server to which you're connected. Your SqlClient code needs to connect to the local end, then traffic will be conveyed over the SSH connection to the SSH server which takes care of connecting to the remote end.

Comment: @siggemannen  -  I updated the question with errors

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, in my sqlConnectionString I have the remote port that is allowed by the remote router, to forward traffic to the PC. But that port that is forwarded to the PC is different from the port that mssql listens on - 1433.  Should I change mssql's listening port, or request changes at the router to accept RemotePort traffic, but forward to the remotePC to port 1433 ?

Comment: Perhaps you need to update your question with more information. e.g.: your ssh command `ssh userName@<remoteRouterIP> -p <remotePort>` doesn't include any parameters that would be required to create a tunnel on the connection (e.g.: `-L 127.0.0.1:1433:192.168.47.47:1433`), so how is `sqlcmd -C -S localhost -U SA` actually working? Do you have an instance of SQL Server installed locally as well? And if you already have an SSH tunnel established from the commandline why are you trying to establish another one with SSH.NET?

Comment: My ssh connect  and subsequent `sqlcmd` command via terminal was just to show that SSH in fact works - I work on the server PC via SSH at times. With regards to this question; I want to access remote SQL data with my C# application only - if that is easiest / best practice I don't know. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ok I got it working - `new ForwardedPortLocal("127.0.0.1", <remotePort>, "127.0.0.1", 1433);   Thanks for the tips @AlwaysLearning.   Should I post the code that worked?